# How can I compare char characters?

Tags: java, char, logical-operators

Why this Java code doesn't work ?
How can add logical comparison like `||` or `$$` to type char in the `if` statement :

```
System.out.println("Type Text");
txt = ms.next();
size = txt.length();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    if ((txt.charAt(i)) == ('a'||'b')) {
        System.out.println("is the letter A or B");
    }

}
```

Comment: Java does not work like this. Please read about operators

Comment: Replace if ((txt.charAt(i)) == ('a'||'b')) {  with  if (txt.charAt(i)) == 'a' || txt.charAt(i)) == 'b') {

Comment: `(txt.charAt(i) == 'a' || txt.charAt(i) == 'b')`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot specify the `||` operator between two `char`s to mean this character or this other one as you try here :

```
if ((txt.charAt(i)) == ('a'||'b')) { ...}
```

`||` is a logic OR that has to be placed between two boolean expressions such as :

```
if (txt.charAt(i) == 'a' || txt.charAt(i) == 'b'){
   ...
}
```

[The Operators tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.htm) is a very good reference to summarize the operators in Java (essentially about their description and precedence).
To avoid the duplication you can introduce a local variable :

```
char c = txt.charAt(i);
if (c  == 'a' || c == 'b'){
   ...
}
```

To specify more logical ORs, using a collection that contains the valid chars is an interesting possibility :

```
if (Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c').contains(txt.charAt(i)){
   ...
}
```

To improve the performance (if you have many valid characters), you could use a `Set`:

```
if (new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c')).contains(txt.charAt(i)){
   ...
}
```

If the conditional statement has to be used multiple times, instantiating the collections a single time is better.